# Does Cron have a way to include all except one case

Tags: cron, splunk

**Goal**

Create a Cron expression that will run a task at 2 pm and 4 am every day to run a Splunk alert

Except for only run the 2 pm task on Thursday (don't run the task a 4 am on Thursday).

**Question**

Is this an expression that can be represented in a single expression? (if so how).

Answer (score 2):

Edited:

Agree with Simon, you can configure 2 separate cron schedules:

1st expression(skipping Thursday) - “**At minute 0 past hour 4 and 14 on every day-of-week from Monday through Wednesday and every day-of-week from Friday through Sunday.**”

```
0 4,14 * * 1-3,5-7
```

Cron expression for Thursday:

```
0 14 * * 4
```

Comment: Sorry, this does not answer the question. This expression includes the 4 am. A task on Thursday something I'm attempting to avoid.   I'm DV, for now, I will adjust if you can update the answer.

Comment: The question *was* answered by Simon Duff and Anant Naugai.

Answer (score 1):

You can't express that in Cron.

Suggest you go with 2 separate from expressions, both times on all days expect Thursday, and then a separate Cron task just for the 2pm task on Thursday